# Connect and detect multiple arduinos using firmata

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, python, firmata

i am trying to connect several arduinos to usb ports and have the abillity to define between them.

i added Firmata.attach function on the arduino board. how do i call it from my python script?
thank you

```
#define BOARD_NAME '1'        
void readName() {
      Firmata.sendString(BOARD_NAME);
    }

void setup()
{
  Firmata.attach(READ_NAME, readName);
  Firmata.setFirmwareVersion(FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MAJOR_VERSION, FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MINOR_VERSION);

  Firmata.attach(ANALOG_MESSAGE, analogWriteCallback);
  Firmata.attach(DIGITAL_MESSAGE, digitalWriteCallback);
  Firmata.attach(REPORT_ANALOG, reportAnalogCallback);
  Firmata.attach(REPORT_DIGITAL, reportDigitalCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SET_PIN_MODE, setPinModeCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SET_DIGITAL_PIN_VALUE, setPinValueCallback);
  Firmata.attach(START_SYSEX, sysexCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SYSTEM_RESET, systemResetCallback);

  // to use a port other than Serial, such as Serial1 on an Arduino Leonardo or Mega,
  // Call begin(baud) on the alternate serial port and pass it to Firmata to begin like this:
  // Serial1.begin(57600);
  // Firmata.begin(Serial1);
  // However do not do this if you are using SERIAL_MESSAGE

  Firmata.begin(57600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for ATmega32u4-based boards and Arduino 101
  }

  systemResetCallback();  // reset to default config
}
```

Comment: with pyfirmata.